# Cloudfront with private EC2 origin

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

I want to integrate cloudfront with private origin as all the instances will be in private subnet with outpost setup.

while creating cloudfront distribution I tried adding private DNS of EC2 (ip-XX-XX-XX-XX.us-east-2.compute.internal) but its giving error : 502 bad gateway

I have below questions :

1. Can we have aws cloudfront with private origin (EC2 instance) ?
2. Can we use cloudfront as a shared proxy cache inside private subnet ?

Answer (score 6):

Amazon CloudFront lives on the Internet. When it retrieves content from an Origin, the content must be accessible from the Internet.

Amazon EC2 instances in a private subnet are *not* accessible from the Internet. Therefore, CloudFront would not be capable of accessing the content.

Private IP addresses can only be resolved and used within the VPC. They are not accessible from outside the VPC.

Comment: Is there any way we can connect cloudfront to our private network?

Comment: You will need to expose your private resources to the Internet so that CloudFront can reach them. You could configure access so that only CloudFront can access the resources, but it is a large list of IP addresses: [Locations and IP address ranges of CloudFront edge servers - Amazon CloudFront](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/LocationsOfEdgeServers.html)

Comment: What about placing an ELB in front of the EC2 instance? would that be sufficient to allow CloudFront to forward the traffic without having to make the instance public?

Comment: Yes, but the Load Balancer would need to be accessible from the Internet so people could potentially bypass CloudFront and access the Load Balancer directly (unless you restrict it as suggested above).

Comment: Can we have NAT gateway to connect to internet from private subnet and configure cloudFront with EC2 instance within private subnet ?

Comment: A NAT Gateway is used to provide **Outbound** access to the Internet for resources inside a VPC. It intentionally does _not_ permit **Inbound** connections from the Internet or, therefore, from CloudFront. If you want your resources reachable from CloudFront, they either need to be in a Public Subnet and accessible to CloudFront, or you need a Load Balancer in a public subnet that is accessible to CloudFront.

Answer (score 2):

A good practice for this would be to use IP prefix list - available as part of VPC functionality.
There you would find managed Cloudfront IP Prefix list, you can reference it in your Security group ingress/egress rules. Updates of this list are managed by AWS.

Additionally, if you are using any other CDN’s, such as Cloudflare, you can populate your own prefix lists and manage in similar fashion your SG rules. Mind that custom prefix lists you have to manage yourself - something I employ myself Lambdas for.

Answer (score 0):

use an internet facing ALB with a custom header rule to determine if the query was from cloudfront.

you can then configure your cloudfront distribution to forwards that custom header key & value so that only requests through cf will pass through

Comment: Or you can just use the IP prefix list and only allow inbound requests from CF. That is much easier than doing what you suggested, which is not even safe as anyone could send these headers.

Comment: @T3rm1 The technique described by silvercondor is what AWS prescribe: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/restrict-access-to-load-balancer.html Anyone can send a header value, but the idea is that the value is a secret only known to owner of the AWS Account (other solutions involve rotating the secret regularly). Using an IP prefix list alone allows anyone to send traffic via CloudFront to your origin; It is easier, yes, but it is not going to secure the origin to disallow others to access it via another CloudFront distribution.